# Swap byte order endianness on struct array, or combine 2 bytes to a word

Tags: arrays, c, endianness

I want to read a file header of a binary and for now just print some values. Code is Big endian. My PC Little endian. Struct has words and strings.
I managed reading from the file but the output was wrong.

Sample bytes are 02 00 00 0c 00 fa.

Output is "Header length= 2 (what is 0002 instead of 0200), height dec= (dec. value of fa00, instead of 00fa)

I also want a conversion of the values themselves and not just a corrected output print.

I searched for many hours here and tried many codes, but none worked and most code had several lines.
After that I tried it by reading 2 bytes (on several ways) like "BYTE (hlen[1]) and [2], hlenlow.

I previously had a working code with bytes (and not with struct but buffers) like

```
printf(" Pixel dec %u\n", (uint16_t)(buffer[6] << 8) | buffer[7]);
```

but now I want to convert bytes to words with the correct byte order. I have to convert them sooner or later when working with them.

Header length is up to 1024 bytes and I don't want to manually convert every single one.

Also how to print bytes with "00" and the leading 0 of 02? I always had issues.
Strings might be another issue later (how to check the length inside).
And later there are variable color palettes depending on the header length.
I checked lots of other codes but none is similar or extremely difficult to understand (like many inc files). What is the best and simplest way? Best with converting all bytes (except the 3 strings)

```
typedef unsigned short WORD;
struct header{
WORD (hlen); 
WORD (datatype); 
WORD (height);
char date [8]; 
..
}

// file io with fp

struct header input;
fread(&input, sizeof(struct header), 1, fp);
printf("Header length =%X%X\n", input.hlen);
..
printf("height dec=%u%u\n", input.height);
```

Comment: Post definition of `buffer` of the _working_ code.

Comment: What do the bytes 00 0C designate?  The basic technique is to read the bytes and combine them by shifting and masking as appropriate.  If the 6 bytes are a sequence of three 2-byte integers in little-endian order, then you read each pair of bytes (as 2 separate bytes) and combine the two values.  Beware signed vs unsigned quantities (especially as plain `char` can be signed or unsigned).  It's not all that hard, but it is marginally fiddly.

Comment: `02 00` to be decoded as `2` is little endian order.  Double check this, because you are interpreting thing wrong.

Comment: unsigned char buffer[511]; 000C is the datatype, same issues. Sequence of 2 Bytes but big-endian, at least all is swapped. Files written on m68k. The image file format supports signed, unsigned and other data but this comes later. Fiddly, so to hard for me. Can someone post some code or tell me where to find some. There must be samples for that. Maybe I should write this on a big-endian machine. I'm also stuck with a custom RLE decoding on another thread.